# Can two solid objects pass through each other if they are moving sufficiently fast relative to each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, pauli-exclusion-principle

The reason two solid objects can't pass through each other is from the Pauli Exclusion Principle that states that two identical fermions can't occupy the same state at the same time.  If two solids were moving sufficiently fast relative to each other would having very different velocities allow them to occupy the same place in position space without their electrons occupying the same state allowing them to pass through each other?

Comment: Only if you could turn of all interactions between the two solids. The electromagnetic interactions will still be at work.

Comment: As you may know, it's not just the electrons that cause problems re the exclusion principle, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html#c1